# Firebase android auth email already exist special trigger

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to trigger toast to say that user with same email is already registered. In my code toast triggers when there is something wrong with registering. For example password is too short. But when user is trying to register with email that is already taken he doesn't know that. Please help me, and tell how should i edit my code?

```
private void registerUser(){
    String email = editTextemail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextpassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter email ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "registration complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email is invalid or password contains less than 6 symbols", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code after else:

```
progressDialog.dismiss();    

String message = "The email address is already in use by another account."       

if (task.getException().getMessage().equals(message))  
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
else     
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email is invalid or password contains less than 6 symbols", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```